# React native apk generation fails

Tags: react-native

After building the project the APK is generated but it throw the below error when trying to open the app in Android phone.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you are building a DEBUG type apk, which require JS bundling every time you start the app. You can run `react-native start` at your project root to startup the metro bundle.

Alternatively, you could build APK for RELEASE mode. Check your project structure, make sure `debuggable` is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app in release mode then your can try below command :

> react-native run-android --variant="release"

**Note:** If you have not generated keystore for your project you have to generate it. You can generate keystore by following official doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-an-upload-key).

Answer (score 0):

i think you generate a debug APK, first you must generate a key using jdk ->  [here is the official doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-an-upload-key), here is the summary

1. generate a keystore
2. place the generated keystore inside **android/app/**
3. Setting up Gradle variables  in **android/gradle.properties**
4. add release code to **android/app/build.gradle**
5. in cmd to generate apk use

   **cd android && gradlew assembleRelease**
6. the output apk will be in android\app\build\outputs\apk\release
7. in cmd if you want to generate a bundle use

   **cd android && gradlew bundleRelease**